# PROBLEMAS CON FileNotFoundException en C#

Tags: c#

Intento crear un programa de consola en el que ingreses un numero del 1 al 10, una vez ingresado este numero el programa buscara un archivo de texto con la tabla de multiplicar del numero, si lo encuentra mostrara por pantalla linea por linea la tabla del mismo, en caso de que no lo encuentre envié un mensaje indicando que no se ha podido encontrado la tabla.
El problema esta en que cuando se ingresa un numero en el que no hay tabla, el mensaje que deseo que aparezca no aparece, en cambio aparece un mensaje de error predeterminado de Windows.
Utilice un try y un catch para evaluar que el archivo exista, sin embargo el catch no funciona como quiero.
Desde ya muchas gracias y espero que me lo puedan solucionar.
Adjunto Codigo:

```
using System.IO;

Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un numero para ver su tabla de multiplicar");
        int a=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        string nom_archivo="tabla_"+a+".txt";
        StreamReader miArchivoL=new StreamReader(nom_archivo);
        try{
            string linea=miArchivoL.ReadLine();
            while(linea!=null){
                Console.WriteLine(linea);
                linea=miArchivoL.ReadLine();


            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            
           throw new FileNotFoundException("La tabla que usted intenta visualizar no existe");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La instruccion [try-catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/exception-handling-statements#the-try-catch-statement) soporta que puedas definir en la clausula cath cual es la excepcion "especifica" o incluso "varias exepcciones" para poder de las mas especifica a la mas general "tratarlas". Incluso soporta "filtrar" con la clausula [when](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/exception-handling-statements#a-when-exception-filter) que exepcion necesitas capturar.

En tu caso, no te funciona porque ni bien salta una excepcion [FileNotFoundException](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.filenotfoundexception?view=net-7.0) lo atrapas en el catch y luego la vuelves a lanzar con [throw](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/exception-handling-statements#the-throw-statement) que produce o lanza una excepcion.

Deberias realizar algo asi

```
try{
    
    //acciones
}
catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
    //Capturar la excepcion mas especifica primero...
   Console.WriteLine("[Error] La tabla que usted intenta visualizar no existe");
}
catch(Exception ex){
    //Cualquier otra excepcion no contemplada...
   var mensaje = string.Concat("[Error] Hemos encontrado un problema no contemplado > ", ex.Message);
   Console.WriteLine(mensaje);
}
```

Como veras tiene 2 bloques [catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/exception-handling-statements#the-try-catch-statement), lo que tienes que conocer

- Se ejecuta en orden, de arriba para abajo (la primera que valida ahi ingresa)
- Solo se ejecuta un bloque "catch" (la primera que valida ahi ingresa)
- Por eso la mas general se encuentra al final

Tambien puedes "filtrar" en cada catch utilizando [when](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/exception-handling-statements#a-when-exception-filter) pero en este caso particular no lo necesitas, pero es util conocer su comportamiento

Enlaces que te pueden servir de ayuda o guia

- [Instrucción try-catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/exception-handling-statements#the-try-catch-statement)